# Как работать с данными после JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть вот такого вида json данные:

```
[
  {
    "fio": "Ivan Ivanov",
    "phone": "111" 
  },
  {
    "fio": "Alix Zizov",
    "phone": "222"
  }
]
```

Я их получаю в js и преобразую с помощью JSON.parse() //let newArr = JSON.parse(data)
Как теперь перебрать объект newArr, чтобы на каждой итерации узнать отдельно fio и phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = '[{"fio":"Ivan Ivanov","phone":"111"},{"fio": "Alix Zizov","phone":"222"}]';
var newArr = JSON.parse(str);
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
  console.log(newArr[i].fio, newArr[i].phone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так: `const phones = newArr.map(rec=>rec.phone)`.

Всё зависит от того, что вы хотите дальше сделать